# how to push a csv of different datatypes to a mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb, csv

Have to push data of csv into mongodb database using python.My csv contains datatypes of float,datetime & string format.But after passing the data to mongo it reflects as string.

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
import sys, getopt, pprint
from pymongo import MongoClient
csvfile = open("C://test1//Jan02//final-current.csv", "r")
        reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile )
        mongo_client=MongoClient() 
        db=mongo_client.January
        db.segment.drop()
        header= ["Instrument Name", "Date", "High", "Low", "Open", "Close", "V"]
        for each in reader:
            row={}
            for field in header:
                row[field]=each[field]
            db.segment3.insert(row)
        csvfile.close()
```

My output:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54aa38eafb2a03c4f4b46e78"),
        "Instrument Name" : "HAVELLS15MARFUT",
        "High" : "280.85",
        "Low" : "280.85",
        "V" : "1000",
        "Date" : "2015-02-01 13:40:00",
        "Close" : "280.85",
        "Open" : "280.85"
}
```

But i chacked in my csv,it shows open,high,low,volume,close in float type & Date in datetime datatype.The result projected is string.Help me to rectify the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So as it is, most CSV parsers in whatever language you choose will just take the input values as strings. It's clearly going to be to your code to change the values to something else. So what do you think you might do here? The only thing that might make this a little cleaner is by employing an ODM to manage the type conversion code for you.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple option is just to convert the data using a mapping dict:

```
csv_values = {"Instrument Name": "my_header", "High": "100", "Low": "56"}
header = {"Instrument Name": str, "High": int, "Low": int}
for k, v in header.iteritems():
    new_value = v(csv_values[k])
    print new_value, type(new_value)
```

Output:

```
100 <type 'int'>
56 <type 'int'>
my_header <type 'str'>
```

just decide the data types of your data and bind a conversion function, you can use much more complex function and to check the data integrity also, At the end just save it to MongoDB.

Comment: Conversion part done already,while passing in mongodb i.e at mongodb end i'm getting it as str

Comment: You need to convert before inserting to mongo, by your example you have inserted to mongo only strings.

Comment: yes before inserting into mongodb i converted the strings to float & datetime format.but still the error is coming